# Breakpoints not working at set breakpoints

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So my breakpoints do not seem to be lining up. The 'sm' screen seems to be set at 1055px.

Theme.js

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      xs: 0,
      sm: 600,
      md: 960,
      lg: 1280,
      xl: 1920,
    },
  },
});

export default theme;
```

Navigator.js

```
const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const matches = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('sm'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example

```
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      xs: 0,
      sm: 600,
      md: 960,
      lg: 1280,
      xl: 1920
    }
  }
});
```

Make sure to wrap your app with `ThemeProvider`

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
   <App />
</ThemeProvider>
```

And in component

```
import { useTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import useMediaQuery from "@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery";

export default function App() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const matches = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("sm"));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <span>{`theme.breakpoints.down('sm') matches: ${matches}`}</span>
      <div>value: {theme.breakpoints.values.sm}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you switch to mobile/table/desktop resolution, `matches` returns true/false.

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/media-query-hook-1jmj6?file=/src/index.js